# Cardinality of set of limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let $S$ be subset of real with usual Topology.
$T$ be set of all isolated points of $S$.
What can we say about the cardinality of $T'$.
Where $T'$ denotes set of limit points of T.
I have found examples of $S$ such that $T'$ can be countably infinite set.
Is it possible that $T'$ can be uncountable set ?

Comment: Take $T=\{(p/q,1/q)\mid\ \gcd(p,q)=1,\ 0\leq p<q,\ p,q\in\mathbb{N}\}$. You can get as close at you want to any point $(r,0)$ with $r\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @plop That is an example in $\Bbb R^2$ not $\Bbb R$ as the OP wants. For an actual example, form a (countable) set by choosing a single element from each of the (countable) components of $[0, 1] \setminus C$ where $C$ is Cantor set.

Comment: How does it work? Please explain ?

Comment: What will be the set of limit points for the chosen set ? @0XLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. consider the set of midpoints of the open intervals deleted in the construction of the Cantor set.

Comment: How does it work ? Please explain

Comment: What will be the set of limit points for the chosen set ?

Comment: @Monotonic the whole Cantor set, and that set consists only of isolated points. So $S=T$ is countable and $T' $ is size continuum.

Comment: Within $\epsilon$ of any point of the Cantor set there is one of these open intervals.

Comment: Yes I understood.